# React JS not accepting cookies from express sever

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, axios, jwt

I'm sending cookies from express server (`res.cookie()`) but this ain't working with my front end even though I include `{withCredentials:true}` in the get requests but it just doesn't work in the browser, no cookies are set in the application tab in browser.
BUT if I try the requests with postman the middleware works perfectly and cookies are shown.
I tried different browsers and different devices, but none.
cors config:

```
app.use(
  cors({
  
    credentials: true,
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:3000", 
    ],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],

  })
);
```

cookie parser config:

```
app.use(cookieParser())
```

this is the get request to check if the user is already logged in :

```
    await axios
        .get("http://192.168.0.141:3001/login", { withCredentials: true })
        .then(async (response) => {

            if (response) {
                loggedIn = true
            }
        })
        .catch(async err => {

            loggedIn = false
        })
```

the middleware of jwt :

```
const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = req.cookies["access-token"]
    if (!accessToken) { return res.status(400).json({ error: "user not authenticated" }) }
    try {
        const validToken = jwt.verify(accessToken, "test");
        if (validToken) {
            req.authenticated = true
            return next();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: error });
    }
}
```

If you need more clarification please tell me , thank you for helping

Comment: You are not executing axios part from the nodejs/server side, are you?

Comment: axios is from the front end, while in the back end there is a an app.post and app.get ,

Comment: the problem is that the request with postman works perfectly and returns a jwt token but performing the requests from the front end doesn't work ,there's just no cookies returned to the front-end

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that no cookies are set? How are you checking that? Does the response contain the `Set-Cookie` header? What cookie parameters are you using (secure, same-site?). Remember that cookies in a browser are saved under the domain which set the cookie. If you're checking in the Application tab of developer tools, then you have to open the developer tools on `http://192.168.0.141:3001` not on `http://localhost:3000`. In your SPA's Application tab you won't see those cookies, but the browser should send them with any XHR request, so you should see them in the request's `Cookie` header in the Network tab.